# Unscope content of Less mixin (equivalent of react-portal but for LESS code)

Tags: css, reactjs, less

Imagine the following code:

```
.myMixin() {
  div.someClass {
    border: solid;
  }
}

div.parent {
   background: red;
  .myMixin();
}
```

It compiles to:

```
div.parent {
  background: red;
}
div.parent div.someClass {
  border: solid;
}
```

But is there a way, *by modifying only the mixin declaration*, to achieve the following?

```
div.parent {
  background: red;
}
div.someClass {
  border: solid;
}
```

---

I'd like something like that where the `@portal` annotation permits to "unscope" the mixin content.

```
.myMixin() {
  @portal
  div.someClass {
    border: solid;
  }
}
```

---

My requirement may seems a bit weird, but trust me, for our company's codebase it makes a lot of sense. If you want insights on why I need that, check what is [react-portal](https://github.com/tajo/react-portal). It permits to declare a react component as a child, but actually it will render directly inside body (so it unscopes the portal component). I am looking for the equivalent system for styling. One could argue I can simply call my mixin outside of the scope, but in our codebase we scope everything and the client of that mixin should not even have to be aware that the mixin is a portal (decoupling: mixin client should not know mixin implementation details at all)

Comment: Nope, not as far as I know because once you nest a mixin under another selector, the contents of the mixin are either assigned to that selector itself  (if using &) or gets treated as a child.

Comment: Yes, there's no way. There's corresponding feature requests of course but it barely will pass (Less is now under control of anti-kludge guys and their definite answer to stuff like this is: "Do not use nesting to group related styles"... E.g. you can group your related classes by comments, files, whatever. Nesting is for *Nesting* only).

Comment: thanks @seven-phases-max I hesitated to open a new github issue btw. Do you know if it's better with Sass?

Comment: Yes, Sass has `@at-root`, which is exactly what you're looking for. Less doesn't currently have an equivalent.

Comment: @Peeja great thanks! unfortunatly I'm using Less :)

Comment: Unfortunately, so am I. :)